# MultiLine TextBox Not Submitting

Tags: c#, asp.net-ajax, textbox, updatepanel

I am writing an asp.net page, and I'm having some trouble submitting the form. What I have is a multiline text box. When the user hits enter, the form should submit, but instead it is inserting a new line (this is usually the opposite problem people have). Here is the relevant body code:

```
<div align="left">
        Name:

            <asp:TextBox ID="Name" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>

            <asp:Button ID="Clear" runat="server" onclick="Clear_Click" 
                Text="Clear Chat Log" UseSubmitBehavior="False" />

        </div>
        <br />
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="UpdateTimer" EventName="Tick"/>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Go" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <asp:TextBox id="Chat" runat="server" ReadOnly="true" TextMode="MultiLine" Width="400" Height="630" />
                <asp:Timer runat="server" Interval="500" OnTick="Timer_Tick" ID="UpdateTimer"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
        <asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
            <Triggers>
                <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="Go" EventName="Click" />
            </Triggers>
            <ContentTemplate>
                <br/>
                <asp:TextBox id="Message" runat="server" Width="400" Wrap="true" Height="40px" 
                    TextMode="MultiLine" AutoCompleteType="Disabled" AutoPostBack="True"/>
                <asp:Button id="Go" runat="server" Text="Go" Width="40px" Height="40px" OnClick="goClicked" UseSubmitBehavior="true"/>
            </ContentTemplate>
        </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

My guess is that the problem is the update panels. Basically, the "Go" button should fire if the user hits enter in the "Message" textbox (these are both at the bottom of the listing)

Thanks for your help,
Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to trap the key Enter at multiline textbox and then submit the form; with Javascript. A sample:

```
<input type="text" id="txtMultiline" onkeydown="if(event.keyCode == 13) document.getElementById('btnSubmit').click()"/>
```

Comment: Yeah I eventually found this solution elsewhere, marking as the answer

Answer (score 0):

Try Ctrl+Enter. Plus, Facebook message page has similar behavior, but you can select the mode: "Quick reply" vs button.

Answer (score 0):

Add another TextBox, like this:

```
<asp:TextBox ID="txtSubmitOnEnter" runat="server" Width="0" style="visibility:hidden;display:none;" />
```

It should work after that.

Comment: Is there any place special I should put this? I tried putting it inside the updatepanel and outside it and neither worked. Could you explain why this should work? Is it something to do with the UpdatePanel?

Comment: I had the same problem once before, where I wanted users to be able to hit enter in the search bar to execute the search, and that was the solution that worked. Try putting the other textbox right below the submit button. I don't know why it works, but it's worked for me.

Comment: Unfortunately this isnt working. I suspect the updatepanels are messing it up

Comment: Can you try setting the AutoPostBack property of the TextBox to false, and see if there's any difference?